# How to check which writers are available for saving an animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I am using matplotlib to make an animation of the evolution of a system over time. I want to be able to save the animation as a file. My default choice is to save as an `.mp4` file, which means I should use the `ffmpeg` writer like this:

```py
anim.save(filename="system_evolution.mp4", writer="ffmpeg", fps=30)
```

The problem is that I am sharing my code with my classmates who don't necessarily have `ffmpeg` installed on their systems. In this case, I would like to fall back to saving a `.gif` of the animation using `pillow` (most of them install Python using `Anaconda` so they probably have `Pillow` installed as well). How can I check which writers are available to use for saving the animation?

I would like to have something like this:

```py
if ffmpeg_available():
    print("Saving system_evolution.mp4")
    anim.save(filename="system_evolution.mp4", writer="ffmpeg", fps=30)
elif pillow_available():
    print("Saving system_evolution.gif")
    anim.save(filename="system_evolution.gif", writer="pillow", fps=30)
else:
    print("Please install either ffmpeg to save a mp4 or pillow to save a gif.")
```

I couldn't figure out how to actually check if `ffmpeg` or `pillow` are available, which means the program crashes when I try to save an `.mp4` and `ffmpeg` isn't installed. How can this be checked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.MovieWriterRegistry.html), the `writers` object in this module has a method called `is_available()` which can be used to check if a specific writer is available.

You can do sth like that

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def ffmpeg_available():
    return animation.writers.is_available('ffmpeg')

def pillow_available():
    return animation.writers.is_available('pillow')

if ffmpeg_available():
    print("Saving system_evolution.mp4")
    anim.save(filename="system_evolution.mp4", writer="ffmpeg", fps=30)
elif pillow_available():
    print("Saving system_evolution.gif")
    anim.save(filename="system_evolution.gif", writer="pillow", fps=30)
else:
    print("Please install either ffmpeg to save a mp4 or pillow to save a gif.")
```